# this jQuery only works in IE

Tags: jquery

There`s actually two problems, one of which is browser specific. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated....

1. If you click the white box `class="submit"` box in the middle of the page at this [sandbox site](http://quoraquora.com/index.php) the background image changes and a program continues in Internet explorer, but it doesn`t continue in Firefox...

**This problem #2 is solved**
2. If you click the white box, it's supposed to trigger a change in the background image, but that's not happening in Internet Explorer (--obviously haven't gotten that far in other browsers where the white box is not clickable...)

the original css to establish the background image is

```
body {background-image:url('kissum.jpg');}
```

The unworking code to change the background image is

```
   var img1 = "url('subway.jpg')";

$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(){
$("#body").css({background: img1});
```

Note, I have also tried

```
var img1 = "url('subway.jpg')";

$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(){
$("#body").css({background-image: img});
```

Comment: there were multiple javascript errors on the page when i accessed your site.

Comment: @david, all the javascript was broken for a second as I altered something, but now I still have the browser problem described in the updated #1 of OP. Do you see an error that would explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`#body` refers to the element with id of `body`.

Try `$('body').css({background: img1});`

Comment: thanks, it sort of works (the background image changes), but if compare firefox and IE, Firefox doesn`t continue with the same program that IE does after the image changes...do you happen to see any reason why

Answer (score 0):

java.js@31

You have an error on that line where you use `#.submit` instead of `.submit`.

Comment: thanks, I changed it. Unfortunately, that doesn`t seem to be the reason why the program is stopping in Firefox (in comparison to IE)